# Simple example of using wx.TextCtrl and display data after button click in wxpython - new to wx

Tags: python, wxpython

I am learning python and trying out wxpython for UI development (dont have UI exp either).
I have been able to create a frame with a panel, a button and a text input box. 
I would like to be able to enter text into the textbox and have the program do things to the text entered into the box after I click the button. Can I get some guidence as to how to do this? for example, lets say I want to display the text entered into the wx.TextCtrl control on the panel.. How would i do that?

```
import wx
class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your quote :", pos=(20, 30))

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Save", pos=(200, 325))

    self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your name :", pos=(20,60))
    self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Enter here your name", pos=(150, 60), size=(140,-1))


app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = ExamplePanel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To do any GUI interactions you have to bind events to the widgets. You basically tell the wxPython app which method (event handler) should be called when some event (button pressed) occurs.

I would also consider learning sizers and using them for your layouts. I have changed your example a bit.

```
import wx
class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)     
        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Your quote:")
        self.result = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="")
        self.result.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save")
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Your name:")
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(140, -1))

        # Set sizer for the frame, so we can change frame size to match widgets
        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)        

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.quote, (0, 0))
        self.sizer.Add(self.result, (0, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname, (1, 0))
        self.sizer.Add(self.editname, (1, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, (2, 0), (1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        # Set simple sizer for a nice border
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Use the sizers
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)  
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)  

        # Set event handlers
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self, e):
        self.result.SetLabel(self.editname.GetValue())

app = wx.App(False)
frame = ExampleFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```